# What am I doing wrong in this loop for image pixels?

Tags: php, image, gd, libraries, pixel

```
<?php

$img = imagecreatefrompng("cuack.png");

$imagew = imagesx($img);
$imageh = imagesy($img);

$width = array();
$heigth = array();          
$x = 0;
$y = 0;

for ($x = 0; $x <= $imagew; $x++) {

    $rgba = imagecolorat($img,$x,1);
    $alpha = ($rgba & 0x7F000000) >> 24;

    var_dump($alpha);
}

for ($x = 0; $x <= $imageh; $x++) {

}
```

I'm trying to check every pixel in an image for transparent pixels, but I'm receiving the following error:

Notice: imagecolorat() [function.imagecolorat]: 1920,1 is out of bounds in C:\www\index.php on line 18

Comment: Just as some advice for posting on here, when you put your code in make sure you take a look at the preview and see if it looks well-formatted. You're much more likely to get answers if people can quickly look at your code and understand it.

Answer (score 7):

The boundaries start at 0 and thus extend to *width* − 1 and *height* − 1 in each direction. Therefore, the `<= $imagew` needs to be `< $imagew`. Likewise for `<= $imageh`.

Width and height just tell you how many rows and columns of pixels there are, *not* the maximum row or column *index* (which is one lower).

To walk the whole image, just use two nested loops:

```
for ($y = 0; $y < $imageh; $y++) {
  for ($x = 0; $x < $imagew; $x++) {
    // do whatever you want with them in here.
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Sorry for the lame question, I have 3 days of php. Any ideas how to mix ever combination from $x and $y to check every pixel in the image? I'm trying to merge the values but I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: See the edit. Usually ask different questions for different problems, though.